# How to test acid-base reactions under pressure?

Tags: acid-base, experimental-chemistry, equipment, pressure

I am trying to test chemical reactions, more specifically reactions between an acid and a base, at different levels of pressure.

I would like to know if there is some kind of equipment I can get that has adjustable pressure, and will let me get the reactants into the vessel without changing the pressure significantly.

I am looking for something that I just get at home, so not too big, and hopefully not too expensive. It doesn't need to be super high-tech, as I'm not going for a high level of accuracy, and I'm not going to be testing extremely low or high pressures.

Does anyone know of any equipment that will create significantly different levels of pressure, even if it is very expensive?

Comment: > I am looking for something that I just get at home, so not too big, and hopefully not too expensive.  || No such thing. Also, pressure within 50 bar (reasonably cheap to obtain in a lab) do not affect acid-base reactions significantly.

Comment: Dang. Oh well, thanks for the reply. I'll have to think of something else.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does anyone know of any equipment that will create significantly different levels of pressure, even if it is very expensive?

Comment: google for 'hi pressure lab reactor'

Comment: What kind of pressure ranges did you have in mind?

Comment: I agree with permeakra but it's worth noting that for a couple of important acids and bases (e.g. CO2, NH3 and possibly CH3COOH) pressure does significantly affect acid base chemistry.  [and OK, CO2 is not an acid but an acid anhydride, you got me.]